# Can't view the pointclouds in the rviz

Tags: rviz, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the bumblebee2 get stereo picture of the left and right image,and use the stereo_image_proc package to deal with it . i got the rect image and disparity image with no problem, and use the command of "rostopic echo /stereo_camera/pointclouds2",got the pointclouds data as followed
[image: image description]
then i want to use the rviz to see the pointclouds picture ,it failed.
[image: image description]

I think it's not the problem of "tf data",as i use the bumbleebee on line get the pointclouds picture by rviz have the same warn of "tf data",but it's no matter to view the pointclouds in the rviz!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236004/can%27t-view-the-pointclouds-in-the-rviz/) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's hard to parse your last sentence. I guess you were able to display an image. In this case, I do think it is the lack of tf data, as the pointcloud data needs a coordinate frame, while the image does not.

In this case you need to manually set rviz to the right frame. Check the output of `rostopic echo  /stereo_camera/pointclouds2/header/frame_id` and set the according frame name as fixed_frame in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2016-06-08**:
Thanks for your advise!
I mean i can get the pointclouds picture with the warn""Global statas warn No Tf data" when i use the bumblebee, so i don't think it lack of tf data.And my frame_id is "map" in my code,so i think it's not the problem.Is there any other posible prolem? I really confused!

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-08**:
In what code is your frame_id "map"? Usually one does not use "map" as the frame_id for the sensor data. Have you checked the output of the mentioned command?

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2016-06-21**:
In my "publish images and camera_info" code.
Thanks for your suggestions, and i found the problem recently. It's the problem of the CameraInfo!. The CameraInfo isn't match the left and right image!

**Comment by [dpetrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/40203/dpetrini/) on 2019-03-13**:
Could you please point what you fixed in CameraInfo? I have exact same problem. thanks